# yii2 PHP Sessions stopped working (was working before, no code/composer updates)

Tags: php, apache, session, yii2

PLease note: this is NOT a csrf issue - it was working until a few days (CSRF enabled, which for security it should be).

This morning I noticed I couldn't log in to my site. Or rather, I could log in but not visit any authentication-required page (it would simply redirect to homepage).

Then after some investigation, found there to be 16million files in /var/lib/php/sessions, which I figured might be the issue. So I deleted all those files.
(rm'ed the sessions folder, which took a while, and recreated it with same permissions, basically following steps here: https://serverfault.com/a/1046464/382503)

Now, when trying to log in to the site, getting error: Unable to verify data submission.
so I added the code to disable the CSRF:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

and deployed. Restarted entire VPS, plus apache2...

Now when I try and log in, it doesn't log me in at all (not getting 'couldn't verify submission' anymore though), simply goes to homepage...no output in any apache log files nor app.log ...

Clutching at straws here as to what to do ...

Any help much appreciated

Update:

I have set the sessions folder to chgrp and chown www-data, and chmod-ed it to 777, so it should definitely be writable:

```
[20:15:35][root@vps12345:/var/lib/php]#ls -l
total 236
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       4096 Feb  7 11:34 emptydir
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root       4096 Apr  8  2019 modules
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 229376 Feb  7 20:15 sessions
```

Also, it seems session files ARE being written to the folder:

```
[20:17:33][root@vps12345:/var/lib/php/sessions]#ls -l | wc
   4189   37694  339240
```

When I delete all files in the folder, and attempt to log in again (still getting same issue, won't log me in):

```
[20:19:13][root@vps12345:/var/lib/php/sessions]#ls -l
total 12
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 23 Feb  7 20:19 sess_9gu45ng49mem7934e8qcap5rr4
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 14 Feb  7 20:19 sess_aog85dp6ovrpn3hq2l14a46nms
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 14 Feb  7 20:19 sess_r18rb7b72a97ku9dv19p1v3js3
```

**Update 2:**
OK, on inspecting the contents of the the session files, it seems its only flash-related stuff (nothing with login session details):

```
[20:32:48][root@vps12345:/var/lib/php/sessions]#for x in $(find . -type f); do cat $x; echo ""; done
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:1:{s:5:"error";i:-1;}error|s:27:"Service category not found.";
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}__id|i:7;
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:1:{s:5:"error";i:-1;}error|s:27:"Service category not found.";
__flash|a:0:{}
__flash|a:0:{}__id|i:69079;
__flash|a:0:{}
```

**Update 3:**
OK, I've enabled DB for session storage (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#custom-session-storage) and the problem is still there so looks like not a file-writing/permission issue

**Update 4:**

OK getting desperate here! None of my site users can log in, this is a disaster for the site :(

Absolutely no code was changed in the last few months. No composer commands have been run. No crons do anything session related.

In fact the **only** change is that I integrated with Ezoic Inc (ads provider). During setup I had to give them access to my CloudFlare username and password so they can access my CloudFlare API key (very scary). Perhaps it's a coincidence ... I don't know.

There's definitely some kind of caching going on too but I don't know if this will affect anything with sessions:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
   die('here'); // this line only comes into effect on POST requests
   
   //rest of login processing code...


}
```

Comment: To me, it looks like php is unable to write to session files. (CSRF protection and login both needs session data to work properly). I would suggest to check that there is enough space left on device where the session folder is and that the session folder is writable by user that runs php scripts.

Comment: Also thought that but not sure what to do ...Have updated question thanks @MichalHynčica. Also in the logs would expect to see an error saying "cant write to session files" or something along those lines (?).

Comment: @gvanto have you checked, is there any redirection on form submission?

Comment: @Govind see answer below, that was issue. Turns out it was caching by Ezoic causing the issue, which they have turned off and now things are working fine again

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally got issue resolved.

Turns out this was Ezoic cloudflare integration causing havoc with my sessions (not saying Ezoic is bad, they seem to have a good product - just need to figure out how to work around this issue).

As soon as CF Integration was removed (in my Ezoic admin area) login started working again...